# Get gstreamer bus messages using non-static message handler

Tags: c++, static, gstreamer, pipeline, static-members

I have created a program using gstreamer which listens to different ports ***(say 5)*** for rtp packets.

Now I have created a class ***(say GstClass)*** which creates the pipeline, and has a Callback function which listens to the bus messages *(I need this message system to shut down the pipeline after a certain timeout)*.

The main function looks like this - 2 threads are created with 2 objects and the GstFunc is called in both threads. The first function would **listen to port 5000** and the second would **listen to port 5008**

```
int main() {

    char filepath1[ ]= "/home/rohan/Tornado1.raw";
    char filepath2[ ]= "/home/rohan/Tornado2.raw";
    unsigned int port1 = 5000;
    unsigned int port2 = 5008;

    GstClass GstObj1;
    GstClass GstObj2;

    boost::thread thrd1 { &GstClass::GstFunc, &GstObj1, filepath1, &port1 };
    boost::thread thrd2 { &GstClass::GstFunc, &GstObj2, filepath2, &port2 };

    thrd1.join();
    thrd2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

the class `GstClass` looks like this -

```
class GstClass {
protected:
    //some other variables...
    GMainLoop *msLoop;

public:

    gboolean bus_call(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message,
        gpointer data);

    void GstFunc(char *filepath, unsigned int *port);

};
```

For detailed function view please look at [this example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html). Replace the function `int main (int   argc, char *argv[])` with `void GstFunc(char *filepath, unsigned int *port)` with appropriate changes.

The `GstFunc` looks like

```
void GstFunc(char *filepath, unsigned int *port)
    GMainLoop *loop;
    GstElement *pipeline, *source, *conv, *sink;
    GstBus *bus;
    guint bus_watch_id;

    gst_init (NULL, NULL);

    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    /* Create gstreamer elements */
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("audio-player");
    source   = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosrc",       "audiosource");
    conv     = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert",  "converter");
    sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");

    if (!pipeline || !source || !conv || !sink) {
          g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
          return -1;
    }
    /* we add a message handler */
    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
    bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, NULL);
    gst_object_unref (bus);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, conv, sink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, conv, sink, NULL);

    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
    g_source_remove (bus_watch_id);
    g_main_loop_unref (loop);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the dilemma I am facing is with the static function *(in example)* `bus_call(...)`.

Since I am creating 2 pipelines in 2 different threads which are listening to 2 different ports, I cannot have this function as static (shared between the objects). how can I make these 2 pipelines dis-joint from each other? Or how can I get this static `bus_call(...)` to become non-static?

simply removing **static** keyword didn't help and giving this error

> error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘gboolean GstClass::bus_call(GstBus*, GstMessage*, gpointer)‘

**Few Imp points**

I have referred to [this document](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/bus.html) which says *To use a bus, attach a message handler to the bus of a pipeline using `gst_bus_add_watch()`*

The `gst_bus_add_watch()` in the `GstClass::GstFunc()` *(which callbacks the bus_call)* is mapped to the header file **gstbus.h** and the the declaration is simply

```
GST_API
guint gst_bus_add_watch(GstBus * bus, GstBusFunc func, gpointer user_data);
```

My initial guess is that the `gst_bus_add_watch` is expecting the 2nd parameter to be a static function. I am not sure why though. What can be done here?

*********************** **Question Edit 2** ***********************

Is it possible to add an argument to the `bus_call` like `gboolean bus_call(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message,gpointer data,**SOME POINTER TO THE OBJECT**)`?

This way the function will **remain static** while having a pointer to the object calling it, and acting upon the objects *(say close pipeline of that object)*.

Comment: do you ever call the method `bus_call` ? Please include a [mcve]. Simply removing the keyword `static` cannot help, because you need an instance to call a non-static method

Comment: Yes I do, Updating the post

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do you pass *pointers* to the integer "ports"? Even if you need to pass the "ports" on as pointers, then you can use the address-of operator *then*, and instead pass the values by value to the threads.

Comment: Hi @user463035818 Please see the updated post. The use of `bus_call` is given as I have used in my program. I have just manipulated the pipeline elements to form the simplest pipeline. _The pipeline works if the function `bus_call` is kept static_

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually this is not the complete code. The values of port here can be given directly as values :) I have tried to post only the required thing to this problem instead of the whole project. :)

Comment: GStreamer is a C-only API, it doesn't know anything about C++ objects. And non-static member functions needs an *object* to be called on (which becomes the `this` pointer inside the function). Can you set some *user-data pointer* or similar? Then you could have a `static` wrapper function that then calls the non-static member function.

Comment: @user463035818 Well Thanks for your suggestion, really appriciate your help :) . I know that this might not be very descriptive for some users, but It is not possible to go in details of a third party api functions. Here the `gst_bus_add_watch` is a function declared in `gstbus.h` file which is one file in the pool. I have simply given the link to the gstreamer webpage in the post. (which I understand, might not help that much)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Do you mean like this? `bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(bus, this->bus_call, loop)` It didn't work. And do I need to create object for calling a function from the same class? I suppose here the `gst_bus_add_watch` is expecting the parameter `bus_call` as static. How can I change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get away with what you want. The signature for GstBusFunc(), the callback, is for a pointer to function, not pointer to member function. They're [different things](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types). (I've also failed with std::bind, fwiw).

I've done something very similar to what you describe, though not quite the same, but I took a different approach that might help you. You *can* use a static method, but you must pass a pointer to your pipeline class to gst_bus_add_watch. Inside your busCallback you dereference the pointer and off you go! You may need to implement some kind of locking scheme as well.

```
class MyPipeline {

   GstElement *m_pipeline;

   public:

   MyPipeline(...);
   static void gboolean busCallback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer p);

}

MyPipeline::MyPipeline(...)
{
    // create pipeline...

    m_pipeline = ...;

    // bus callback, pass 'this' as arg for callback

    GstBus *bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(m_pipeline));
    gst_bus_add_watch(bus, &MyPipeline::busCallback, this);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    // ...
}

gboolean MyPipeline::busCallback(GstBus *, GstMessage *msg, gpointer p)
{

    // get lock if needed...

    // recover your class instance
    MyPipeline *myPipeline = (MyPipeline *)p;

    // do what you need to, free lock

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Ohh, That is what I have done before. I i know that this works. But the problem is I am making 2 objects of this class, and I can't have the callback function static.

Comment: Can you comment on whether you made different objects in your code? And were you wble to close one of the pipeline using this? If not, Can you suggest whether it will be possible? I have tried this way and failed at my end. Can you may be give a bit more suggestion on how you or from where you got this? Meanwhile, I am also looking for another way (might be completely different than this)

Comment: So what exactly does not work for you? There should be nothing wrong having multiple instances of objects which have a static method..

Comment: @RC0993 I use different objects, but they all share the same static callback. The pipelines are created and prerolled on the fly, stopped and freed (state set to NULL).  You can get into trouble if you try to change the state of your pipeline from the wrong place - it cannot be done from the streaming thread (i.e. inside an event probe). I'm sorry I don't have time to post a more complete example right now.

Comment: @howlin_walleye Thanks for the inputs, It worked exactly how you suggested. Earlier I missed to pass `this` while calling back.